# How do you send signals through geological formations

Tags: discrete-signals

Does anyone have suggestions for performing the above?  Presently, in my job we send signals through geological formations; however, if the rock is too dense, then we are unable to receive any signals.

The signals must be sent from a battery-powered transmitter.  Here is an article I've found sending neutrinos, but I am more interested in sending electromagnetic radiation:

http://www.gizmag.com/neutrino-messaging/21842/

Comment: You're not going to be able to communicate with neutrino at any reasonable rate. You should say more about your problem. How far do you want to communicate?

Comment: It is about 3500 meters at the most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For digital communications, bit error rate performance is all about [$\frac{E_b}{N_0}$, the *energy per bit* divided by the *noise power spectral density*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eb/N0). The part that you can control is the energy per bit. Energy per bit is equal to $\text{(average power)(bit duration)}$. You can increase $E_b$ (and therefore decrease your bit error rate) in two ways:

1. Raising your transmitter power. This may or may not be possible based on the hardware you're using, the frequency band in use, and any governmental regulations for your locale.
2. Decreasing the bit rate (i.e. give more time per bit). In cases of extremely high path loss, like communication into caves, you can get reliable operation at a very low bit rate (although other issues such as long-term oscillator stability can come into play and diminish the gain that you might expect).

Communication into deep geological formations is something of a niche application, so you may have trouble finding a lot of literature on suggested approaches. There are companies who specialize in making this type of equipment, so it may serve you better to consult the marketplace for existing solutions that might be off the shelf instead of trying to engineer one from scratch (if your budget permits, of course; I expect such systems to be expensive due to the rather small market).

Comment: The marketplace for existing solutions is mainly in the area of mine safety.